Open same folder in 2 VS Code windows
I want to open a same folder in 2 different windows of VS Code and I want to work on two different branches with them. Is it possible? If yes then please tell me how.
I tried opening a new window using CTRL+SHIFT+N and then opening the same folder in it but then nothing happened.

"I want to work on two different branches with them." Which version control are you working with?

Although it's possible to do this (how depends on which version control system you're using), I wouldn't recommend doing this as it will be easy to make changes on the wrong branch.

If you want to work in two different branches, then you need to be in two different folders, you cannot have two different code branches checked out to the same folder.

Clone the project to a 2nd folder
Open the second folder in a second instance of VSCode.


Ok, my answer is wrong. Turns out Git has this awesome feature 'worktree' which allows you to have multiple branches checked out in one repo.

Thanks for answering @Paul ... I'll try it it work tree.
